# Clicking a button inside CollapsiblePanel on Toggle

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the following CollapsiblePanel jQuery plugin:
http://www.darreningram.net/jquery-collapsible-panel-plugin-2/

On my web page I have a Repeater, where every Item contains a CollapsiblePanel and a Button.

```
<Repeater>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Panel runat="server" class="collapsibleContainer">//this panel becomes collapsible
         <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="Button1"/>
         ...other stuff...
      </Panel>
   </ItemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

I want to trigger the Click Event on Button1 and run the event handler in code behind whenever the CollapsiblePanel is toggled.

So I go to the CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick function in CollapsiblePanel.js and add the following:

```
$(this).parent().children("#Button1").trigger('click');
```

or

```
$(this).children("#Button1").trigger('click');
```

But nothing happens. The event doesn't fire.

I tried to add UpdatePanel around Button1, still nothing.

How can I make it work? Thanks.

Edit: This is the jQuery code I'm changing:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
        // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
        return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-widget");

    // Check if there are any child elements, if not then wrap the inner text within a new div.
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
    $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>");
    }    

    // Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class="collapsibleContainerContent ui-widget-content"></div>");

    // Create a new div as the first item within the container.  Put the title of the panel in here.
    $("<div class="collapsibleContainerTitle ui-widget-header"><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));

    // Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new title div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);
}

function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    // The item clicked is the title div... get this parent (the overall container) and toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().find("#Button1")`. perhaps am not sure what your `$(this)` refers here.. Post some Js code where you have this line if possible..

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to  click the button from the panel

`$('.collapsibleContainer').click(function(){
    //Do your stuff
});`

OR

If your intention is to call a function onClick of the Collapsible panel then call that call that function from inside "CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick"  in CollapsiblePanel.js

Comment: I'm not ever going to click the button myself, but I need to call the `Button1_Click` event handler in code behind.

Comment: I also need to know which RepeaterItem it fired from. Hence the Button.